# Silverlight ComboBox SelectedIndex Changed Load other Control Component

Tags: c#, silverlight, selectedindex

I had made a main page and use user component to implement the style of master page website. i make a drop down combo box to allow user choose their role in the combo box, may i know is that possible to call another user control with C# code beside from xaml while i need to do some logic statement.

i got one master page, loading another component with this combobox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbRole" Height="30" Margin="8,8,8,100" VerticalAlignment="Top" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Please select your role to login" SelectionChanged="cbRole_SelectionChanged">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Admin"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Lecturer"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Student"/>
    </ComboBox>
```

and the master page load the combo box with this line

```
<betata_Views_Sidebar:Sidebar/>
```

and i got a question on how to do this -->

```
private void cbRole_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         int x = cbRole.SelectedIndex;
        if (x == 0)
        {
            <betata_Views_Sidebar:Sidebar_Admin/>
        }
        else if (x == 1) 
        {
            <betata_Views_Sidebar:Sidebar_Lecturer/>
        } 
        else if (x == 2)
        {
            <betata_Views_Sidebar:Sidebar_Student/>
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you load them all and depending on the selected index, alter the visibility of the components?

Comment: ouch >.< Thank you.. i totally forgotten this =D Thank you

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help!

Comment: sure =D you helped =P last time i did in that way but i forgotten >.<